# multiple non ansi join

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I am asked to use non ansi join for the given query:
Q) Display the records from the above tables with the following fields –
Employeeid, employee name, department id, department name,
start_date of job, end date of job, job title, country name, region name, Difference in the maximum salary and the Employee’s salary

Tables given to us are standard in "hr" connection tables in Oracle 11g

I used the following query:

```
select e.Employee_id,
         first_name,
          e.deparment_id, 
         department_name,
          start_date,
          end_date,
          job_title, 
         country_name,
          region_name,
           (select max(salary) from employees)-salary
from employees e, 
     countries c, 
      departments d,
      job_history jh,
      jobs j,   
      locations l,
      regions r
where e.deparment_id = d.department_id 
and jh.employee_id = e.employee_id
and e.job_id = j.job_id
and d.location_id = l.location_id 
and l.country_id = c.country_id
and c.region_id = r.region_id;
```

The output I am getting is redundant on certain entries.
I need help resolving the redundancy.

my output

```
101 Neena    90 Executive      28-10-93 15-03-97 President                     Unites States of America Americas  7000
101 Neena    90 Executive      21-09-89 27-10-93 President                     Unites States of America Americas  7000
102 Lex      90 Executive      13-01-93 24-07-98 Administration Vice President Unites States of America Americas  7000
200 Jennifer 10 Administration 01-07-94 31-12-98 Administration Assistant      Unites States of America Americas 19600
200 Jennifer 10 Administration 17-09-87 17-06-93 Administration Assistant      Unites States of America Americas 19600
176 Jonathon 80 Sales          01-01-99 31-12-99 Sales Representative          United Kingdom           Americas 15400
176 Jonathon 80 Sales          24-03-98 31-12-98 Sales Representative          United Kingdom           Americas 15400
201 Michael  20 Marketing      17-02-96 19-12-99 Marketing Manager             Canada                   Americas 11000
```

desired output is where there wouldn't be any redundant data like we can see 'Neena' or 'Jonathon' repeating.

Comment: Are you not getting desired output? if not, then show us the desired output and what you are currently getting?

Comment: What incompetent would want you to use implilcit joins?

Comment: You need to show us what you mean by redundant on certain entries. Likley it is just that the tables are in a one to many relationship.

Comment: please refer the edits

Comment: @HLGEM - doubtless a homework assignment. This doesn't really answer your question, though... :-)

Comment: @HLGEM There are a few rare cases where Oracle requires or benefits from the old-fashioned syntax.  For example, fast-refresh materialized views and bitmap join indexes still do not work with the ANSI join syntax.  It would help if Mihir would clarify exactly why he has such an odd requirements.  (Bob's probably right, this is homework.  But even for homework this is a strange requirement.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you have is a cross join: your join conditions don't identify unique keys for each table, so one or more tables with multiple records is causing repetition of "unique" attributes.

Without the source data it;s hard to be sure, but I'd guess it's the JOB_HISTORY table: the START_DATE and END_DATE values are unique in each row.  The easiest way to fix this would be an additional join on JOB_ID:

```
and e.job_id = jh.job_id
```

Adding this condition should cause the JOB_HISTORY rows return only the latest role for the employee.

Comment: certainly did!! only not the one you suggested...     `e.hire_date = jh.start_date`     did the trick :D

Answer (score 0):

You could use `USING` instead multiple `WHERE` clauses. You need to clarify your question.

Comment: Thank you! However this is the question that I received in textual format... I've pasted it... I will try using     `USING    `